# Has the word "vaping" become the synonym of inhaling the weed aka marijuana?

Tags: word-usage

Recently I have begun to see the word "vaping" at Yahoo such as [**this**](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/mom-whose-son-nearly-killed-145835142.html), quote,

> Weeks after the frail college student returned home in July, two investigators from the FDA knocked on the family’s front door, peppering Walker with endless questions about **where he purchased the mango-flavored pods** that he vaped in his Juul e-cigarette.

or [**this,**](https://news.yahoo.com/vitamin-e-acetate-used-thc-123427754.html) quote, (also see the title)

> **State officials are reconsidering their marijuana regulations** and quality control in the wake of investigators’ discovery that 29 patients with vaping-related lung illness tested recently had greasy vitamin E acetate from THC in their lungs.

I suspect these appearances have something to do with the rise of the use of POD or weeds or marijuana which has begun to be legalized in many states in the U.S. (In our country, even holding the seeds of Marijuana leads to the arrest.) I am asking this question since in our country there started to have appeared many weed related arrests of so-called "celebrities" (including cocaine) and when I take a look at news at Yahoo America, this vaping thing comes to my mind. Thank you for any info in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Vaping](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/vape)** is the [broadly used term in the US](https://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/basic_information/e-cigarettes/severe-lung-disease.html) for the use of e-cigarettes whether they contain nicotine or THC/marijuana-derived chemicals. E-cigarettes are commonly called **vapes** or **vaporizers**.

[This article](https://www.livescience.com/41211-how-electronic-cigarettes-work-infographic.html) describes the mechanism by which vapes work. The gist of it is that there is a replaceable cartridge with a liquid that contains some oil, flavoring and drug content. When used, the liquid is heated until it turns into vapor, and inhaled.

Vaping does not refer to the traditional method of smoking marijuana or cigarettes.